# A $C^1$ fucntion $f$ on $\Bbb R^2$ that has no mixed second derivative

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Is there a $C^1$ function $f$ on $\Bbb R^2$ that have no mixed second derivatives? (Here, mixed second derivative means $f_{xy}$ or $f_{yx}$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $f(x,y) = x^2y \sin(1/x)$. The partial derivatives

$$\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,y) &= 2xy \sin(1/x)-y\cos(1/x)\\
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y) &= x^2 \sin(1/x)
\end{aligned}$$

are vanishing at the origin and continuous. Hence $f$ is $\mathcal C^1$. However, $f_{xy}$ is not defined at the origin.